# Rank of a matrix with block matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

So, given $A\in M_{3{\times}4}(R)$ has rank $2$, I built a new matrix -

$M=\begin{pmatrix}
A&  0& A\\ 
0&  A& 4A\\ 
 0&  0& 0
\end{pmatrix}$

Can I claim, that since the rank of $A$ is $2$, and the rows of $M$ are LI, the rank of $M$ is $4$?

Thanks

Comment: Not "the rows of M are l.i.", but **two** rows of $\,M\,$ are l.i. ...when the rows are blocks of matrices, of course.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. So given two of the rows of $M$ are LI, where the rows are blocks of A, the rank of $M$ is 4?

Comment: Yes, because the l.i. rows of $A$ in $M$ are below zeros.